# Grails: How to include an html link inside a <g:message> default attribute?

Tags: grails, internationalization

I am starting with Grails and want to have one page with multilanguage content.

I started using the  tag which works fine.
But here is what I want to do:

I want to include the default text of the default language right in the text, to avoid switching back and forth in between files.

```
<g:message code="homepage.feature.headline1" default="This is an english text" />
```

The above works.

But now I a have a message which should include a link like this:

```
<g:message code="homepage.feature.headline1" default="This is an english text with <a href='somefile.html'>a link</a>" />
```

This gives me an exception:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.exceptions.GroovyPagesException: Error processing GroovyPageView: Grails tags were not closed! [[<g:message>]] in GSP
```

How can I achieve that I can include a link there? I have tried escaping the <> brackets but still no luck.
I really would like to avoid splitting up this one sentence into multiple smaller sentences.

Thanks
Christoph

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two possible ways:

```
<g:message code="homepage.feature.headline1" default="This is an english text with ${'<a href=\'somefile.html\'>a link</a>'}" />
```

or

```
<% def link = "<a href='somefile.html'>a link</a>"%>
<g:message code="homepage.feature.headline1" default="This is an english text with $link" />
```

Comment: Thanks Fabien. I go with Option1. The advantage is, that the template developer can already see the default text without looking into the message.properties. Option2 is good as well but too much code for this purpose.
Thanks
Christoph

Answer (score 5):

Closures can be used for nested i18n messages. I find it useful for when the link generation needs additional logic.

```
<g:message code="homepage.feature.headline1" default="This is an english text with a {0}" encodeAs="raw" args="[link(controller: 'someController', action: 'someAction') { message(code:'homepage.feature.headline1.link')}]"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually create 2 messages: the original one and the key other to be replaced. This makes it optional to create the link or not. Considering both keys are provided (leaving the verification out of this snippet):

```
packagesUpdate.error.server.unreachable=The packages repository server "{0}" is unreachable. This usually happens behind a network proxy server.
packagesUpdate.error.server.proxyReplace=network proxy server
```

- Replacing the string in the controller, e.g., on ref msgWithLink:

  ```
  def msg = message(code: 'packagesUpdate.error.server.unreachable')
  def proxyReplace = message(code:'packagesUpdate.error.server.proxyReplace')
  def msgWithLink = msg.replace(proxyReplace,
      "<a href='/csvn/packagesUpdate/available'>${proxyReplace}</a>")
  ```
- Replacing in the g:message tag:

  < g:set var="msg" value="${message(code:'packagesUpdate.error.server.unreachable')}" />
  < g:set var="proxyReplace" value="${message(code:'packagesUpdate.error.server.proxyReplace')}" />
  < g:set var="link" value="${proxyReplace}" />
  < g:set var="msgWithLink" value="${msg.replace(proxyReplace, link)}" />